# Why do I have a problem when I visualising the testing set results?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, logistic-regression

As a beginner, I am working on the Titanic Survival dataset [The data is here](https://github.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/blob/master/titanic.csv) and applying LOGISTIC REGRESSION to them. After cleaning my data as shown below:

[image]

I would like to Visualise the test set results based on the below code to know the survivals and nonsurvival people.

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_test, y_test
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('magenta', 'blue')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('magenta', 'blue'))(i), label = j)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[69], line 6
      3 X_set, y_set = X_test, y_test
      4 X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
      5                      np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
----> 6 plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
      7              alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('magenta', 'blue')))
      8 plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
      9 plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:419, in LinearClassifierMixin.predict(self, X)
    405 """
    406 Predict class labels for samples in X.
    407 
   (...)
    416     Vector containing the class labels for each sample.
    417 """
    418 xp, _ = get_namespace(X)
--> 419 scores = self.decision_function(X)
    420 if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    421     indices = xp.astype(scores > 0, int)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:400, in LinearClassifierMixin.decision_function(self, X)
    397 check_is_fitted(self)
    398 xp, _ = get_namespace(X)
--> 400 X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
    401 scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T, dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    402 return xp.reshape(scores, -1) if scores.shape[1] == 1 else scores

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:588, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    585     out = X, y
    587 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):
--> 588     self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
    590 return out

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:389, in BaseEstimator._check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    386     return
    388 if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
--> 389     raise ValueError(
    390         f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    391         f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
    392     )

ValueError: X has 2 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 6 features as input.
```

**Any assistance, please?**

I would like to show something like the one below: The figure below for other dataset.

[image]

The whole code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    training_set = pd.read_csv('Train_Titanic.csv')
    sns.heatmap(training_set.isnull(), yticklabels=False, cbar=False, cmap='Blues')
    #if we want to dop Cabin column from the memory we set implace=True 
    training_set.drop('Cabin', axis=1, inplace=True)
    training_set.drop(['Name','Ticket','Embarked'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    sns.boxplot(x='Sex',y='Age',data=training_set)
    
    def Fill_Age(data):
        age = data[0]
        sex = data[1]
        
        if pd.isnull(age):        #if the data has null
            if sex is 'male':
                return 29         #This is average from the above boxplot of male
            else:                 #This means if the sex is female 
                return 25         #This is average from the above boxplot of female
        else:
            return age            #This will return the same age if it isn't null
    training_set['Age'] = training_set[['Age','Sex']].apply(Fill_Age, axis=1)
    training_set.drop('PassengerId', axis=1, inplace=True)
    male = pd.get_dummies(training_set['Sex'])
    male = pd.get_dummies(training_set['Sex'], drop_first=True)
    male = pd.get_dummies(training_set['Sex'], drop_first=True, dtype=int)
    #Let's drop Sex column from our original data
    training_set.drop('Sex', axis=1, inplace=True)
    training_set
    #Now, let's add the male column that we have created to the original dataset
    training_set = pd.concat([training_set, male], axis=1)

#Now let's take our data and assign it to X (input) and y(output)
X = training_set.drop('Survived', axis=1).values
X

y = training_set['Survived'].values
y

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 10)
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression # We import class (LogisticRegression)
    classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)     # We took an object from the class
    classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)      
    #We are performing our training
    y_predict = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Post the data as text instead of [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Also, how have you defined your classifier?

Comment: @SurajShourie I edited the post and this is link for the data https://github.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/blob/master/titanic.csv

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line? `classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T)` Your classifer will expect a input of the same shape as your `X_train`, which this is not

Comment: @SurajShourie I got this idea from another example; I am not fully aware of it, because I am a beginner and try to learn, dear sir.

Comment: OK, then in your visualization, what feature ("Age", "Fare" etc.) do you want X or Y axis to be, like the FB ad viz uses estimated salary vs time spent

Comment: bevcause you can make predictions like this: `y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)` but then you need to have clarity on what your viz is supposed to look like